# git_index_get_byindex vs git_status_foreach_ext

Tags: libgit2

It looks like `git_index_get_bypath` and `git_status_foreach_ext` (with `GIT_STATUS_SHOW_INDEX_ONLY`) are just different ways of reading the index. What are the differences, and why would I use one vs. the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git_index_get_bypath` lets you look up a particular entry a given index.

`git_status_foreach_ext` does a status check, which is a comparison between the worktree, the index and `HEAD` and iterates over the results of that comparison calling the passed function. With that flag, it would skip the worktree in that comparison.

Which one to use depends on what you're looking for: a particular entry in the index or a list of differences between the index and `HEAD`.